# Asana task field "hearts" user ids

Tags: api, asana

Asana task field `hearts` contains user ids that are not equal to the workspace's user ids. Is that a bug or a feature?

According to the api documentation:

**hearts**

```
[ { id: 1123, name: 'Mittens' }, ... ]
```

Read-only. Array of users who have hearted this task.

Answer (score 2):

Note: a Heart is an object in its own right, with its own ID. If you want the ID of the User who "created" the heart, you need to use `hearts.user.id`, which is the same as the ID of the user in the workspace (i.e. you could do `GET /users/:id`).

Example using `?opt_expand=hearts`:

```
 "hearts" : [
     {
        "target" : {
           "name" : "Task name here",
           "id" : 1234 // ID OF TASK
        },
        "id" : 1235, // ID OF HEART
        "user" : {
           "name" : "User name",
           "id" : 1236 // ID OF USER
        },
        "created_at" : "2015-11-30T12:40:13.516Z"
     }
  ],
```

Comment: That makes kind of sense, however a heart object isn't mentioned anywhere in the api documentation. `?opt_expand=hearts` doesn't work for me. On what endpoint is that supposed to work?

Comment: The example I gave was on a call to `GET /tasks/:id`, but you could also do e.g. `GET /projects/:id/tasks?opt_fields=hearts.user.id` (if you specifically want the user ID)